# Adding an hyperlink button to the XForms textarea control

Tags: xforms

I am new to Xform. I want to use rich text editor in my page. So I used the attribute `mediatype="text/html"` on my `<xforms:textarea>`. Now the rich text editor appeared for my page. But it doesn't have all the controls; e.g. it doesn't have an hyperlink button. What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by overriding [`tinymce-config.js`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/tinymce-config.js) and add the `link` buttons, at the end of `theme_advanced_buttons1`. When done, this is how the button will look like. And for more settings, see the [advlink](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:advlink) plugin.

[image: Link button]

Comment: Hi avernet, thanx for reply. But I am not getting the file tinymce-config.js in my tomcat folder. where is it located by-default? my path is opt/tomcat/webapps/

Comment: I referred below url for this earlier:   http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/textarea-control

Comment: The `tinymce-config.js` is packaged inside the `WEB-INF/lib/orbeon-resources-public`. You can extract it from there, place it in your `WEB-INF/resources/xbl/orbeon/tinymce/tinymce-config.js`, and modify it there. The version in your `WEB-INF/resources` will override the one in the jar file.